# How to create CombinedGeometry for ellipse and line

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw ellipse excluding cross inside of it. I have a suspision that I need to use opacity mask. Here is how I am trying to do it.

```
Color grey = Color.FromArgb(128, Colors.Gray.R, Colors.Gray.G, Colors.Gray.B);
double radius = Math.Min(ActualWidth, ActualHeight) / 2;
Brush ellipse_brush = new SolidColorBrush(grey);

CombinedGeometry cg = new CombinedGeometry();

Drawing maskDrawing = new GeometryDrawing(Brushes.Lime, null, cg);
DrawingBrush mask = new DrawingBrush(maskDrawing);

dc.PushOpacityMask(mask);
dc.DrawEllipse(ellipse_brush, new Pen(ellipse_brush, 0), new Point(radius, radius), radius, radius);
dc.Pop();
```

Thing is that I don't understand how to create `CombinedGeometry` for ellipse and two lines. Or maybe I am on the wrong path?

Comment: The cross should not be filled, i.e. be drawn transparent?

Comment: @Clemens : Yes, just like cutout

Comment: @Clemens Thank you!!! Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an opacity mask in conjunction with a `CombinedGeometry`.

Create the cross outline geometry from a `GeometryGroup` with two lines and an appropriate Pen, then combine it `Xor` with an EllipseGeometry and draw the result:

```
var radius = Math.Min(ActualWidth, ActualHeight) / 2;
var crossSize = 0.8 * radius;
var crossThickness = 0.3 * radius;
var centerPoint = new Point(radius, radius);
var ellipseGeometry = new EllipseGeometry(centerPoint, radius, radius);
var crossGeometry = new GeometryGroup();

crossGeometry.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(
    new Point(centerPoint.X - crossSize / 2, centerPoint.Y - crossSize / 2),
    new Point(centerPoint.X + crossSize / 2, centerPoint.Y + crossSize / 2)));
crossGeometry.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(
    new Point(centerPoint.X - crossSize / 2, centerPoint.Y + crossSize / 2),
    new Point(centerPoint.X + crossSize / 2, centerPoint.Y - crossSize / 2)));

var crossPen = new Pen
{
    Thickness = crossThickness,
    StartLineCap = PenLineCap.Round,
    EndLineCap = PenLineCap.Round
};

var crossOutlineGeometry = crossGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(crossPen);
var combinedGeometry = new CombinedGeometry(GeometryCombineMode.Xor,
                                            ellipseGeometry, crossOutlineGeometry);

dc.DrawGeometry(Brushes.Gray, null, combinedGeometry);
```